# Why can't I create a HEAD route in Hapi?

Tags: hapi.js

According to the documentation https://hapijs.com/api/16.0.1#route-configuration a route method may not be of the type 'HEAD' but I do not understand why I can not override the behavior.

Answer (score 5):

`HEAD` routes are automatically created with every `GET` route you define. Therefore there's very little reason you'd need to define your own.

> If you want to optimize your handling of HEAD requests, simply check your GET handler for the method, and if it is `head`, return an empty response with the correct headers. This is only worth doing for some very expensive GET requests, where you are expecting clients to use HEAD directly.
>
> The main reason not to support it, is that I am expecting very few developers to use this, but it will add an extra lookup for every HEAD request.

This has been already been addressed [on Github](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/795).

Answer (score 0):

As to further elaborate on @Ankh's response, you can check the request `method` property to abbreviate the response on the GET handler:

```js
const getHandler = (req, h) => {
  // HTTP status 204 -> NO CONTENT
  if (req.method as string === 'head') return h.response().code(204)

  // continue the GET handler logic here
}
```